# Prove that The factor ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z_n$ is an integral domain only when $n$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

During an example the book said a statement without any proof:

> The factor ring $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z_n$ is an integral domain only when $n$ is prime.

Why? Even when $n\neq p$, $\mathbb Z_n$ is commutative and $1\in \mathbb Z_n$ is identity, so $\mathbb Z_n$ is an integral domain for any $n$.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_{10}$ you have $2\cdot 5=0$

Comment: @Ataulfo - I had forgotten the third part of the definition for integral domain. Thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if n is composite then $n=ab$ implies $a\neq0,b\neq0$ but $ab=n=0$ in $\mathbb Z_n$.